# Take a command line argument as the file name to open C++

Tags: c++, file, command-line

So I need to take a command line argument and use that as the file I open, using the following format:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>  
#include <sstream>  
#include <string>  
#include <algorithm>  

int main()
{  
    ifstream inFile;  
    string data;  
    inFile.open("text.txt")  
    .....  
}
```

Followed by more code which inputs the data into an array and then does calculations with it, I just have no idea how to take an argument from command line and use that as the file name instead of text.txt. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
```

argc = count of parameters

argv = parameter array

argv[0] corresponds to the command typed to execute the program.

argv[1] is the first command line parameter.

You have to check if argc >= 2, then use argv[1].